# Please help to find grille clips

Tags: windows

My husband and I bought a home a few months back and a lot of the window grilles are falling off the window. The clips that hold them are broken. Its a beautiful log home and the window looks better with the grilles in them but I can not find the clips anywhere. We were told they were Pella windows. They are not. I contacted Pella and Anderson and they both said they were not their windows. I now have a picture of some numbers in the lower part of one of the windows but I don't know how to find out what brand they are. Also I have a picture of the clip I can attach to see if anyone else has them or knows anything about them. I do know the house was built in 2004 we are in Hazle Township Pa 18202 if that info is needed. They are wood windows with wood grilles. The window pulls in from the corners to clean but it is not that easy to do, you have to pull them out of the frame. If needed I can attach a picture of the window as well.
Thank you for any help you can give me.

numbers I finally found on one window:
[image]

another view of the numbers found on the same window
[image]

the clip which is flat and lays flush against the window. there is no lip on the other side
[image]

all wood window
[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what's going on.  Do these clips poke into the stiles and rails, and then the grilles clip on?

Comment: Yes, they usually slip in between the rails/stiles and the glass.

Comment: Yes the open space showing holds the grilles and then the razor part slides between the window glass and the frame of the window. If you look closely at the full window picture you can see a clip holding on the grille. I would ass another picture but I don't think it will let me

Comment: I removed the background from the clip image and did a reverse image search.  Nothing of value turned up.  However, "Grille clip for windows" shows a lot of results.  You may have to settle for something similar, and make small modifications.

Comment: Thanks I tried one already but they break. The ones I have are flush to the window and all the others have a lip. We bought some I found on eBay thinking we could make them work but cant. I was hoping to be able to find out what the numbers on the windows mean and if I can call a company who might have made them. Thank you tho for getting back to me so quickly!

Comment: @JacquelineLoosbrock those numbers on the window seem, imho, to be about the glass and its composition & tempering, not the manufacture of the window / frame.

Comment: Can you find any identifying marks on the window frame?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for SGC 2176 +glass and the results included a site for SGC network which apparently makes glass. You may be able to ask them about the numbers and they may be able to point you to a manufacturer.

Comment: thank you I will try that right now!! More clips broke and soon we will not have any grills in the windows.... Or we will have to figure out another way to put them in which all that we have tried will not work and let us open the windows. The other clips made the grilles stick out too far and the windows will not open then. Thank you again!!

Comment: @JacquelineLoosbrock if you were able to identify the window manufacturer from this info, please come back to give this answer a check-mark. If not, let us know what you did by answering your own question and giving it a check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

Green River Window and Door in Columbus Kentucky. Easy to find on the internet. They supplied window and doors for Barna Log Home packages. Your windows look exactly like ours and we have a Barna Log Home. Barna went out of business after Jim Barna's death but Green River is still in business.

Comment: Green River Window & Door - 504 Fairgrounds St. - Columbia KY. 42728                               Phone # 270-384-3987 Fax # 270-384-9238 - E-mail -chuck@greenriverwindowdoor.com